# Chrome - Message passing - From popup click to context script on specific tab

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, message

Can you tell me why the following code is not working. Here is my code :

Popup.js (not a backgorund script) :

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: url}, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'connect.js', allFrames:true}, function() {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'whatever value; String, object, whatever');
        });
    });
```

content script :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message);
    // Handle message.
    // In this example, message === 'whatever value; String, object, whatever'
});
```

And my manifest :

```
{
    "name": "AN App",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "To connect",

    "permissions": [
        "storage", 
        "activeTab", 
        "tabs", 
        "https://*/*"],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://*/*"],
        "js": ["connect.js"]
    }],
    /*
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },*/

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I don't understand, the console debug in the tab do not display anything...

I also try from the popup to the background and then from the background to the tab but nothing happen neither (I'm quite new at chrome extension so I hope u can help me)

Thanks,

Regards

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I call chrome.tabs.create from the JS inside the popup it closes the code running in the popup and the message is never sent.

So instead of calling the chrome.tabs.create inside the JS linked to the popup, I just send a message to the background script, the background script call chrome.tabs.create (like this it runs in background and the code do not stop from executing).

And then the message function works correctly like chrome doc says.

Martin